# Getting an error in Terminal when running a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, macos-monterey

**Specs:**
MacOS Monterey, no available updates, Python 3.10.4

**Problem:**
I'm getting the error `zsh: segmentation fault  sudo python3` when I try to run this command `sudo python3 '/Users/cyberstorm/Documents/Visual Studio Code/Terminal Adventure/mainCode.py'` This command is trying to run the python file mainCode.py as in administrator using the absolute path. I'm unable to understand why I'm getting this error.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I installed the keyboard module for python so I could use keyboard inputs. I finished coding and using the module. I believe my code is correct. When I tried running the file normally, I got this error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (listen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 294, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.direct_callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keyboard/_darwinkeyboard.py", line 430, in listen
    raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator
```

Thus I wanted to use the sudo command and using `sudo python3 mainCode.py` didn't work because apparently the file didn't exist. So I tried the absolute path, which brings me here.

Comment: did you run it directly in terminal/console or using some IDE? maybe Mac has more complex security system and may need something more. On LInux it also need `sudo `to run `keyboard` but it works.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: what do you want to do with `keyboard`. There are also modules `pynput` or `pyautogui` which doesn't need `sudo`.

Comment: @furas I'm running the code directly in the Terminal as of now.

Comment: @furas I'm trying to code it so that when the user presses "i" during any point of the game, a dictionary should be printed out. Is this possible with other modules?

Comment: @furas - Print debugging... I'll try it out, thank you!

Comment: [pynput.keyboard.Listener()](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) also can catch keys. But sometimes games use non-standard methods to work with devices and modules may not work. You will have to check if `keyboard` or `pynput` works with your game.

Comment: @furas - Okay thank you! I'll try using that method and module. I just finished checking and installing pynput :) Tysm again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245399/discussion-between-cyb3rst0rm-and-furas).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix the issue! I'm not too sure on what happened, more of luck. What I did was run the command (in terminal) `python3 -m pip install keyboard`. I also made sure to properly install and check `pip` using [this site](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#:%7E:text=Run%20python%20get%2Dpip.py,they%27re%20not%20installed%20already.&text=Be%20cautious%20if%20you%27re,system%20or%20another%20package%20manager.). Once I ran the code, making sure there were no errors, it worked! Thanks to all that helped, including on my previous post!